# Personalize JComboBox Java

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I wanted to customize a `JComboBox` so I used a model with `ListCellRenderer` my goal was to change the background of an item by hovering to an orange and I got it.

Example of how it turned out:
[image: Example of how it turned out]

But I change the style of the combo box slightly, it looks somewhat metallic, how could I make it look like the original, that the background color when passing the pointer is not blue but a type of orange, the color code I used was **[255,142,0]**

Example of the original:
[image: Example of the original]

Here I show the code that I use to customize the combo box:

```
public class PropertyCombo extends BasicComboBoxUI {

    Color c = new Color(255, 142, 0);

    public static ComboBoxUI createUI(JComponent com) {
        return new PropertyCombo();
    }

    @Override
    protected ListCellRenderer createRenderer() {
        return new DefaultListCellRenderer() {
            @Override
            public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> jlist, Object o, int i, boolean bln, boolean bln1) {
                super.getListCellRendererComponent(jlist, o, i, bln, bln1); 

                jlist.setSelectionBackground(c);

                return this;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And the code to add this customization to the JComboBox is:

```
cbx_name.setUI(PropertyCombo.createUI(this));
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please read [ask]. Questions on the main Stack Overflow site must be in English. If you'd rather use Spanish there's [the Spanish version](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) where you can post in Spanish.

Comment: Ingles aqui, por favor.  Preguntas en espanol: [es.so]